# Django: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sslserver'

Tags: python, django, ssl

I would like to use https for my Django development server using django-sslserver.

I have installed it using
`$ pip install django-sslserver`

I have then added it to my settings.py INSTALLED APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...                                                                                       
'sslserver',
...
]
```

However, if I now try to start the sslserver like this:

```
python3 manage.py runssslerver 0.0.0.0:8080
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sslserver'
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: can you share the output of pip freeze here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using native python in linux, the `pip` and `pip3` is different. You can try `pip3 install django-sslserver`.

I recommend to use virtual environment in web service development of python, e.g. [pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv).